# Options for redirecting Amazon AWS access through customized website

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

We've developed an application that utilizes the Amazon AWS S3 SDK client to get objects (files) from AWS bucket. This platform would require the system to be able to access s3.amazonaws.com. However, some of our customers do not want to open the firewall to amazon.com (when enter the s3.amazonaws.com to web browser, it redirects to the aws.amazon.com/s3). How can we use our own domain name site to redirect to the Amazon AWS site and be able to get the objects (files) with SDK for .NET?

Thanks,
Baolin

Answer (score 0):

You can use CNAME's to have the `Host:` header be identifiable, but unless you setup a reverse proxy your clients will still have to allow access on their firewall.  See [Customizing Amazon S3 URLs with CNAMEs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs)

If you want to have all client access go through IP addresses under your control, you could use a reverse proxy.  There are many tutorials on setting one up for this specific use case:

- [Nginx as proxy for Amazon S3 public/private files](https://coderwall.com/p/rlguog/nginx-as-proxy-for-amazon-s3-public-private-files)
- [IIS Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing)
- [Apache Proxy for Amazon S3](http://www.mattburkedev.com/apache-proxy-for-amazon-s3/)

You could also proxy the requests in-app.  For example, using MVC Core the [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Proxy` middleware](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Proxy/) allows you to set up a route that gets passed to a third party.

Example taken from [Joseph Woodward's](http://josephwoodward.co.uk/2016/07/proxying-http-requests-asp-net-core-using-kestrel) website:

```
// Startup.cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...

    app.MapWhen(IsAdminPath, builder => builder.RunProxy(new ProxyOptions
    {
        Scheme = "http",
        Host = "localhost",
        Port = "8081"
    }));

    ...

}

private static bool IsAdminPath(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    return httpContext.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith(@"/admin/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

To create a proxy using a windows service, you can use WCF:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceContract(Namespace = ServiceNamespace)]
[DataContractFormat]
public class FileContentService : IFileContentService, INullContract
{
    public FileContentService()
    {
        client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionalEndpoint.USEast1);
    }

    [OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "Files/{fileId}")]
    public io.Stream GetFileContent(string fileId)
    {
        GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest 
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = fileId
        };

        var response = client.GetObject(request);
        // copy relevant headers (MIME, ETag, Cache-Control, etc...)
        // WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.SetETag(etag);
        // WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = foo;
        // WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers
        //     .Add(HttpResponseHeader.CacheControl, "{cache options}");
        return response.ResponseStream;
    }
}

public class FileContentServiceManager : IDisposable
{
    private ServiceHost shThis;

    public FileContentServiceManager()
    {
        shThis = new ServiceHost(typeof(FileContentService), new Uri("https://localhost/foo/bar"));
        shThis.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(FileContentService), GetBinding(), "")
            .Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        shThis.Open();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        shThis.Close();
    }

    static Binding GetBinding()
    {
        var b = new WebHttpBinding();
        b.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 28 * 1024 * 1024 * 2;
        b.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 4096 * 1024;
        b.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32;
        b.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 4096 * 1024;
        b.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 4096 * 1024;
        b.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport;

        CustomBinding result = new CustomBinding(b);
        WebMessageEncodingBindingElement webMEBE = result.Elements.Find<WebMessageEncodingBindingElement>();
        webMEBE.ContentTypeMapper = new MyMapper();

        return result;
    }

    class MyMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
    {
        public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
        {
            return WebContentFormat.Raw; // always
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mitch! I'll try your suggestions and report back if it worked.

Comment: Sure.  If you find that it solves your problem, consider checking the green checkmark next to the answer.  See the helpcenter for more: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Hi Mitch! It seems these suggestions won't work well with my app as ours is a Windows service app instead of Web app. There is not much configuration we can change when using Amazon S3 SDK for .NET. These clients of ours are small number (only about 3 - 4% of the total sites). So, we would not like to make a totally new app either.

Comment: @BaolinLi, I added an example using a self-hosted WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually we used a different way of resolving this issue: we added more specific prefix in the URL to narrow the scope of the access to Amazon sites. The naming convention from AWS requires that the prefixes to be with '-' instead of '.'. For example: instead of using 'myproduct.bucket.s3.amamzonaws.com', we need to use 'myproduct-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com'.